# Pass complex object to params in protractor cli

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to pass in a complex object to the protractor cli for `params` and I'm not getting it to work. I have tried to `JSON.stringify()` it but it doesn't work either. The only thing I've gotten to work is:

```
protractor --params.profiles.search.firstName=richard --params.profiles.search.lastName=davenport
```

When I really want to do something like this:

```
protractor --params='{"profiles":{"search":{"firstName":"richard","lastName":"davenport"}}}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly pass values to params object. Instead create a new key in params object as `profiles` and pass the value for profiles key using `--params.profiles '{"search":{"firstName":"richard","lastName":"davenport"}}'`

in you config.js add below key to params object :

```
params: {
  "profiles" : ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did need to add a key on --params in the cli, but it does not appear to be required in the config file, it is working without it.